# Change radio buttons to check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have the below form with radio buttons and i want to replace them (the 2 options inc no thanks) with simple check boxes - leaving 3 check boxes.

I can't manage to change the JS to get it working... I've tried tweaking the JS but it stops the ability to either calculate or redirect - which is the main form purpose!

Help!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form onSubmit="submitForm();" id="myForm" type="get">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio1" data-op="0" value="10" onClick="calcNow();" selected />Option A&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="myRadio1" data-op="1" value="120" onClick="calcNow();" />No thanks<br/>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio2" data-op="0" value="10" onClick="calcNow();" selected />Option B&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="myRadio2" data-op="1" value="20" onClick="calcNow();" />No thanks<br/>
<input id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="10" onClick="calcNow();" />Otion C<br/>
<input id="myTotal" name="myTotal" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" /><br/>
<input type="button" id="myButton" onClick="submitForm();" value="Continue" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pages = [[["http://mysite.com/page1.html","http://mysite.com/page2.html"],["http://mysite.com/page3.html","http://mysite.com/page4.html"]],[["http://mysite.com/page5.html","http://mysite.com/page6.html"],["http://mysite.com/page7.html","http://mysite.com/page8.html"]]];

function calcNow()
{
    var cb = document.getElementById("myCheckbox");
    var cost1 = getRadioValue("myRadio1");
    var cost2 = getRadioValue("myRadio2");
    var cost3 = cb.checked ? parseInt(cb.value) : 0;
    var costTotal = cost1 + cost2 + cost3;
    document.getElementById("myTotal").value = costTotal;

    var op1 = getRadioData("myRadio1", "op");
    var op2 = getRadioData("myRadio2", "op");
    var op3 = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;

    if (op1 != undefined && op2 != undefined && op3 != undefined)
    {
        return pages[op1][op2][op3];
    }
    return undefined;
}

function submitForm()
{
    var page = calcNow();
    if (page != undefined)
    {
        // ---- To popup ----
        //alert(page);
        // ---- To navigate ----
        location.href = page;
        // ---- To alter post ----
        //var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        //form.action = page;
        //form.submit();
    }
    else
    {

        alert("Please answer all questions.");
    }
}

function getRadioValue(name)
{
  var controls = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
      if (controls[i].checked) {
          return parseInt(controls[i].value);
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

function getRadioData(name, attribute)
{
  var controls = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
      if (controls[i].checked) {
          return parseInt(controls[i].dataset[attribute]);
      }
  }
  return undefined;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code makes me angry. It's one thing to try things, it's another to just guess. I mean, why not put an onCLick handler on your body tag too, heck that might work.

Comment: Ur, sorry! Can you amend the code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you and I don't your Javascript in you case.

There are two suggest.
You replace on the input radio with two input checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myRadio1" data-op="1" value="on" onClick="calcNow();" />No thanks<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="myRadio2" data-op="0" value="10" onClick="calcNow();" selected />Option B&nbsp;
```

This is easy but now it 's difficult.
When the input 's checked, call the function `calcNow()` but when this is unchecked your can't call the function .
But for the management I suggest that your search on GOOGLE.

For me is better that your add the button that call the function `submitForm();`

This is a [example for checked and unchecked](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_checked).

EDIT:

I working on your case and there is a solution [JSDIFFLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/mxPju/2/)

Comment: Thanks Mirko, can i remove the 'Please answer all questions' alert? I also can't check and hide one of the check boxes without it needing to be physically checked off... I've tried:

`checked style="display:none;"`

Comment: Look on the edit's solution, before I was eating

Comment: This is a solution??
Why you set my answer how the better answer?